# Add filter buttons to datagrid column headers

Tags: wpf

I have a working datagrid and I'm exploring ways to add a filter button to my header columns much like how the new Excel does it. The rough sketch below demonstrates the desired functionality. Ideally the button would appear in the top right, if clicked once it would show an itemBox (or something more appropriately) and if clicked again it would close the itemBox.

[image]

So far I've been trying to add a button (step 1) to the Connection Status column but its not coming up.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ConnectionStatus" MinWidth="33">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <!--THIS IS WHERE IM TRYING TO ADD THIS BUTTON-->
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Ellipse Height="15" Width="15" StrokeThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource OnlineStatusConverterStyle}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My question is how do i set up my headers in order to get a button to show up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`DataGridColumn.HeaderTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.headertemplate). You can make a reusable `DataTemplate` and leave the `Header` property for the actual content. Here's a quick example I threw together:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ToggleButton Name="FilterButton" Grid.Column="1" Content="▼" Margin="2, 1, 1, 1" Padding="1, 0"/>
                <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=FilterButton, Path=IsChecked}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=FilterButton}" StaysOpen="False">
                    <Border Background="White" Padding="3">
                        <TextBlock>Some Filters Here</TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Column 1" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Column 2" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I love the template approach. Now, do I make different templates for each of the columns? this is because some columns will have different filters.

Comment: @user2529011 Hmm, I don't think so. I would try to keep one header template and then use code or bindings to customize the `Popup`, since that's the only thing that's changing and everything is will be consistent. For example, you can use the `Popup.Opened` event and then change `Popu.Child` dynamically.

Comment: I like this method. Okay, this is enough to get me going. Again, thanks so much.